# xcode: add a second page in a same tab

Tags: xcode, tabview

when "Tab A - Page One" satisfies some conditions, it will jump to "Page Two". But "Page Two" must also have a tab view bar at the bottom, and tab bar should shows that Page Two is still in "Tab A".

Page Two is a individual page.

How to do that?...

Comment: Show us a graphic example, I didn't understood what you wanted, and what you tried.

Comment: I did draw a graphic example, but stackoverflow did not allow me to upload, do you have an email address which I can send it to you?...

Comment: Upload it on a other web site (there are plenty of image sharer), and paste the link in your question

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/cqkhzj7el/

Comment: Could you see it? ^_^

Comment: I don't see an issue. What have you tried? How does your StoryBoard look like?

Comment: I don't know a standard way to make it happen, if I should add a Navigation Controller at the beginning of tab A? so it could jump to each pages by using "[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextPage" sender:self];" but I don't want the header of Navigation Controller in each page, then I hide the headers in Navigation controller? is that a standard way to do it?

Comment: You need to read a tutorial of how set a TabBar, and iOS dev in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Tab is a view controller and each of your pages are views,

Simple solution would be, just adjust your two views to be in the same view controller, meaning both should have the same coordinates and hide one of them accordingly like if you want to show the first page/view hide second page/view and vice versa.

Comment: thanks very much! it is not what I want, but I think it should be a solution for other people, accepted.